# priorityqueue return front javascript

Tags: javascript, return, priority-queue

how can I do method in javascript to return the value in front of priorityqueue without remove this value from the queue

could you write it with comments because I want to understand step by step 
this is my initial code for priorityqueue

```
function PQueue()
{
 this.pq = new List();          //requirement: linked-list implementation

    // specify (design) methods

    this.isEmpty     = pqEmpty;     //return true if queue empty
    this.deleteMin   = deleteMin;   //remove/return item with minimum priority
    this.insert      = pqinsert;    //insert item with priority
    this.decrease    = decrease;    //updated the priority queue with the new distance value    


}
```

Comment: is it your homework?

Comment: no I my project about Edmonds‐Karp and queue and I want to improve it by do this method but I don't have algorithm for that so I need your help

Comment: So, you're expect to get working PriorityQueue class? with all the methods?

Comment: no I do all this method  I just want to know how can I return first element in priority queue

Comment: I still didn't get what's a problem. Could you clarify it?

Comment: how can Retrieves the head of the queue if it is not empty

Comment: // Just for testing

var v = new PQueue();

v.isEmpty();

v.insert({w: 7});

v.insert({w: 100});

v.insert({w: 1});

v.isEmpty();

v.deleteMin();

Comment: where do you store objects? like `{w: 7}`? :)